# What Default order of beans creating in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What Default order of beans creating in Spring Boot if we don't use @DependsOn and @Order?
I searched for documentation and found only "How to control the order of creating"

Answer (score 1):

From this [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation) (scroll down a bit):

> ...Your target beans can implement the
>   org.springframework.core.Ordered interface or use the @Order or
>   standard @Priority annotation if you want items in the array or list
>   to be sorted in a specific order. Otherwise, their order follows the
>   registration order of the corresponding target bean definitions in the
>   container.
>
> You can declare the @Order annotation at the target class level and on
>   @Bean methods, potentially for individual bean definitions (in case of
>   multiple definitions that use the same bean class). @Order values may
>   influence priorities at injection points, but be aware that they do
>   not influence singleton startup order, which is an orthogonal concern
>   determined by dependency relationships and @DependsOn declarations.